# Error :The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER: D:/Qt/bin/clang/bin/clang.exe is not a full path to an existing compiler tool

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

The general messages on running QT creator to build my code says

```
*Running Windows Runtime device detection.
No winrtrunner.exe found.
Running Windows Runtime device detection.
No winrtrunner.exe found.
Running Windows Runtime device detection.
No winrtrunner.exe found.
Running "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -E server "--pipe=\\.\pipe\{8cd95c25-ccf7-4bd3-92e3-6efb4a56f1b5}" --experimental" in D:\build-tudatBundle-Desktop-Release.
Starting to parse CMake project.
The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:21 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:
    D:/Qt/bin/clang/bin/clang.exe
  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.
  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/build-tudatBundle-Desktop-Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/build-tudatBundle-Desktop-Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
CMake Deprecation Warning:
  The 'cmake-server(7)' is deprecated.  Please port clients to use the
  'cmake-file-api(7)' instead.
CMake Project parsing failed.*
```

What is wintrunner? 
Where do I amend the path as that path doesn't exist. I've configured on QT creator to the right compiler path but it uses this particular path - 'D:/Qt/bin/clang/bin/clang.exe'

Any other sources of error?

Please edit this question to make it suitable for reading. I'm unaware of the format, but I'd appreciate any and all help. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: seems that you assigned a 32bit compiler to a 64bit Qt version

Comment: Hey Vladimir, where does it say that ? and what compiler should I chose. In Qt I assigned MinGW and Clang as possible compiler with accurate paths, and I don't see it in the messages. Should I add a command in the Cmakelists to overwitre the path of the compiler?

Comment: Try to read this question and check your paths for extra white spaces https://stackoverflow.com/q/46004925/4149835