# Using qnx.cmake shows error "CMAKE_C_COMPILER is not a full path to an existing compiler tool."

Tags: c, cmake, qnx

I am using CMake with QNX Momentics. For that I executed the command

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/my-path/qnx.cmake
```

on terminal which shown me the below mentioned error:

```
ERROR:-
"-- The C compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (project):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:
    /home/mobis/MTCI/Test/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/ntox86_64-gcc
  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.
  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH."
```

1. I have checked for `ntox86_64-gcc` compiler in my local pc and it is present at `/hom/Test/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin` location.
2. I have tried to build by giving compiler path at command line with CMake but it shows same error.
3. Tried below solution even after that same error:

   [CMAKE_C_COMPILER is not a full path to an existing compiler tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45140273/cmake-c-compiler-is-not-a-full-path-to-an-existing-compiler-tool)

   ```
   export CC=/usr/bin/gcc
   export CXX=/usr/bin/g++
   ```

Please find below my **qnx.cmake**:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME QNX)
set(CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME QNX)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 7.0.0)
set(arch ntox86_64)
set(QNX_PROCESSOR x86_64)
SET( TOOLCHAIN QNX )

#Check environment variables
if ("$ENV{QNX_HOST}" STREQUAL "")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "QNX_HOST environment variable not set")
endif()

if ("$ENV{QNX_TARGET}" STREQUAL "")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "QNX_TARGET environment variable not set")
endif()

set(QNX_HOST "$ENV{QNX_HOST}")
set(QNX_TARGET "$ENV{QNX_TARGET}")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${QNX_HOST}/usr/bin/${arch}-gcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${QNX_HOST}/usr/bin/nto${QCC_NTOARCH}-g++")


set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL "-Os -DNDEBUG")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3 -DNDEBUG")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "-O2 -g")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -D_DEBUG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL "-Os -DNDEBUG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3 -DNDEBUG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "-O2 -g")

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "${QNX_TARGET}")
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

Please find below my **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14.2)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
project(Test VERSION 1.0     DESCRIPTION "CoreLSP FOlder structure     project"   LANGUAGES C)
set(SRCS 
   main.c
   printing.c
   ) 
add_executable(Test ${SRCS})
```

Expected:

- The project should be built successfully and makefile should be produced so that I could import project into QNX Momentics IDE (Linux based Host OS).

Comment: I have referred  [link] "https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/qt/qnx.cmake" to use qnx.cmake

Comment: CMake tries the exact compiler you set in your toolchain (`CMAKE_C_COMPILER` variable). If this setting is wrong, then fix your toolchain. You may add `message("C compiler: ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}")` into your toolchain for verify that you use the correct path.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for the reply.I added "message("C compiler: ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}")" into my QNX.cmake then i came to know that compiler path in the tool chain was wrong and the path which i got from  message() is "C compiler: home/mobis/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/ntox86_64-gcc"
After setting the above path also still  i am getting the same error with new path
ERROR:
**--The C compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (project)
The CMAKE_C_COMPILER
 home/mobis/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/ntox86_64-gcc
 is not a full path and was not found in the PATH**

Comment: Did you forgot the first `/` character in the path?

Comment: @Tsyvarev shame on me.yes had missed / now it is working.Thank you for the sopport.